# ¿Qué significa abatizar (visto en Nicaragua)?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, definiciones, palabras-raras, nicaragua

He visto la palabra *abatizar* en periódicos de Nicaragua, pero no puedo encontrar la palabra ni en el diccionario de la RAE ni en WordReference.com. ¿Exactamente qué significa *abatizar* y en cuales regiones se usa? Parece que tiene que ver con la fumigación de insectos, pero ¿cómo es diferente que *fumigar*?

Comment: http://www.lasaluddelaspoblaciones.es/expresate_post.cfm?idBlogPost=56 "Abatizar significa fumigar los lugares donde pueden transmitirse la malaria y el dengue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El Abate es una marca comercial de un insecticida, específicamente un larvicida, utilizado para disminuir la población de mosquitos, en particular de los géneros que funcionan como vectores para enfermedades que afectan a humanos.

Es utilizado en México de forma regular en las zonas infestadas con Dengue, donde se mezcla con agua y se rocía en aerosol en terrenos baldíos o áreas donde se pueden criar las larvas del mosquito; tal como menciona belisarius en su comentario, la palabra abatizar es una derivación verbal que trata de transmitir la idea de la aplicación del insecticida Abate.